# Android USB data transfer

Tags: java, android, usb, endpoint

I've got HID which is connected to my Android tablet. HID has only one endpoint (type - interrupt, direction - in). I'm receiving data from this endpoint using queue method from UsbRequest and then i have to send reply to HID. I think that i should use controlTransfer method to do it. 
But i dont know what values i should choose for the first two params of this method:

requestType - request type for this transaction

request - request ID for this transaction

Can someone please explain me how to use this method properly, or may be there's some other way to send reply to HID?